# Complex Analysis Schwarz's Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic function and $|f(z)|\leq3$ for all $|z|=1$, $f(0)=0$. Can $|f'(0)|>3$..?

My Attempt :

From Schwarz's pick lemma

$|f'(z)|\leq$ $\frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}$.
Now putting $z=0$,we have $|f'(0)|\leq$ $\frac{1-|f(0)|^2}{1-|0|^2}$ i.e $|f'(0)|\leq$ 1.So
$|f'(0)|>3$ is impossible..

Am I correct ? Or is something wrong in this process.

Comment: +1 for the good first question, but I deleted the "thank your". See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21039/1107523 for more information.

Comment: Doesn't Schwarz's pick lemma requite $|f(z)| \leq 1$?

Comment: Ohh yes it must satisfy $ |f(z)|<1$. Otherwise how I will proceed? Please help me

Comment: So consider the function $f(z)/3$?

Comment: Achha achha 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your process is wrong, since Schwarz lemma requires that $f$ maps $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ to $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disk. However, you can just use it for $\frac{1}{3}f$, so the result is correct.